# Demographics search in italian language with Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Good day.

Using Facebook Ad I can include public with demographics caracteristics same as education, sentimental relation, work position, etc. in italian language.
With search on Graph API Explorer I can only search some of them in english language excluding locale parameter.
With old version of marketing apis using adeducationmajor, adworkposition, etc, I obtainied the local values of them.
Now not.
It's possibile obtain it in a same way as adinterest?

Best regards.

Stefano Errani

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why the question is incorrect?